# ffmpeg and iFrame output and quality of JPEG

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, images

I was looking for a solution to a problem and on my travels I cane across something linked to what I was doing which prompted a 2nd question.

**I bundled both these questions here. If I should not I will split it into 2 separate question if requested.**

I was looking for way to output an image from my ip camera using ffmpeg from a RTSP strteam.

I found it and it was this (I tested in a DOS prompt)

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.8/video_1 -f image2 -s 360x240 -vf fps=fps=10/60 img%3d.jpg
```

I was looking at a way of controlling the quality of the image. I remember when I encoded serveral jpegs to a video file I would use this:

```
-f image2 -r FPS-i  + MyPath + \img%05d.jpg -crf 23  -y -r 'FPS' + 'oggOut.ogg'
```

Here the quality is set using -crf 23 where the 23 is setting the quality of the image. I have been told the lower the number the better the quality.

Is there a way of specifing image quality in my 1st command line?  I have tried putting the crf everywhere but it tells me flag not recognised.

Whilst looking for a solution I found this page:

[some examples out putting jpeg from a stream](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

The last example on that page stated:

**This will create one thumbnail image every I-frame**

I had understood that an i-Frame is a change in preceding and current frames?  When I tested this it just gave me a stream of images.  Have I mis-understood what an I-Frame is?

Comment: The first line of the FFMPEG page you link to at the bottom of your question would be the one to use. However, because FFMPEG is receiving a live stream from your camera you can't use the time setting in the answer. You will need to repeat the command for each thumbnail you want to generate.

Comment: @BigChris Hi, I just this now worked that out for myself.  I am just trying to work out how to read to the end of stream when the basestream.length property is not available.

Comment: Is the stream of images not what you expected from the "create one thumbnail image every I-frame" example?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hi, I know I got a lot to learn but what is an I-Frame please?

Comment: [Intra coded frames/slices (I‑frames/slices or Key frames)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types#Intra_coded_frames.2Fslices_.28I.E2.80.91frames.2Fslices_or_Key_frames.29) provides a good overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JPG output use `-q:v` to control quality. Range is 2-31. A lower value is a higher quality, and therefore higher file size.

The `-crf` option is used by the encoders libx264 (H.264 video) and libvpx (VP8/VP9 video), but the values vary between these encoders. It is not for mjpeg (JPG images/MJPEG video) or libtheora (Theora video).

Also, you may find the [scale video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to be more flexible than `-s` because you can just declare one dimension and the filter will automatically provide the other while preserving the aspect ratio: `-vf fps=1/6,scale=360:-1`. Using `-s` to force a specific size may result in a squished or stretched output.